# Opening sheet in SwiftUI view

Tags: swiftui, view, parameters, diagnostics

I have the following view in my first SwuiftUI project:

```
import SwiftUI

struct RosaView: View {
    
    @State var rosa: [Rosa] = Rosa.testRosa()
    @State private var apriNuovoGiocatore = false
    @State var stagione: String = "2023/2024"
    var rosaFiltrata: [Rosa] {
        Rosa.testRosa().filter {
            $0.stagione == stagione
        }
    }
    
    @State private var selezioneGiocatore: Rosa.ID? = nil
    @State private var ordine = [KeyPathComparator(\Rosa.ruoloGiocatore)]
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Text("Stagione: \(stagione)")
                .fontWeight(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.bold/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                .font(.headline)
                .foregroundColor(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.blue/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                .padding()
            
                Table(rosaFiltrata, selection: $selezioneGiocatore, sortOrder: $ordine) {
                    TableColumn(Text("Nome").foregroundStyle(.blue), value: \.nomeGiocatore)
                    TableColumn(Text("Cognome").foregroundStyle(.blue), value: \.cognomeGiocatore)
                    TableColumn(Text("Ruolo").foregroundStyle(.blue), value: \.ruoloGiocatore)
                    TableColumn(Text("Data di nascita").foregroundStyle(.blue), value: \.nascitaGiocatore)
                    TableColumn(Text("Età").foregroundStyle(.blue)) {
                         Rosa in
                        Text("\(Rosa.etàGiocatore)")
                    }
                }

            
        }
        .frame(width: 900, height: 400)
        .toolbar {

            Button {
                apriNuovoGiocatore = true
            } label: {
                Image(systemName: "person.badge.plus")
                    .foregroundColor(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.blue/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
            }
            
            .sheet(isPresented: $apriNuovoGiocatore, content: {
                nuovoGiocatore()
            })
        }
            .navigationTitle("Rosa")
    }
    
}

struct nuovoGiocatore: View {
    
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
    
    @State var nomeNuovoGiocatore: String
    @State var cognomeNuovoGiocatore: String
    @State var nascitaNuovoGiocatore: String
    @State var ruoloNuovoGiocatore: String
    @State var etàNuovoGiocatore: Int
    
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationStack {
            Form {
                TextField("Nome:", text: $nomeNuovoGiocatore)
                TextField("Cognome:", text: $cognomeNuovoGiocatore)
            }
            .navigationTitle("Nuovo giocatore")
            .toolbar {
                
                Button("Cancel") {
                    dismiss()
                }
                Button("Aggiungi giocatore") {
                    let nuovoGiocatore = Rosa(stagione: "2023/2024", nomeGiocatore: nomeNuovoGiocatore, cognomeGiocatore: cognomeNuovoGiocatore, nascitaGiocatore: nascitaNuovoGiocatore, etàGiocatore: etàNuovoGiocatore, ruoloGiocatore: ruoloNuovoGiocatore)
                    
                    Rosa.testRosa().append(nuovoGiocatore)
                    dismiss()
                }
            }
        }
        
    }
}

#Preview {
    RosaView()
}
```

I'm getting two strange errors.
The first one is "Missing arguments for parameters 'nomeNuovoGiocatore', 'cognomeNuovoGiocatore', 'nascitaNuovoGiocatore', 'ruoloNuovoGiocatore', 'etàNuovoGiocatore' in call" when I'm calling nuovoGiocatore in sheet.
The second one is in the view nuovoGiocatore and it says "Failed to produce diagnostic for expression; please submit a bug report (https://swift.org/contributing/#reporting-bugs)"

What am I doing wrong???

Thanks in advance for your support,
A.

Comment: You don't have any default values for your `@State` variables, so the compiler is expecting that you're going to pass them in as parameters.

Comment: State should always be private, all State need an initial value from within the View

Comment: Ok thanks - I have added "private" to all the State variables and set the String to = "", while the only one Int = 0. But still, I'm getting the "Failed to produce diagnostic" error. What does it mean?

Comment: That means there is a typo somewhere. Comment out sections of code until you find it